# Diacritics thicker than rest of the letters

Tags: css, font-face, google-font-api

I'm using [Open Sans font from Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) on one of my page, and altho I'm using almost the same style regarding the font as Google does, my diacritics are somewhat thicker than the rest of the letters:

[image]

(you can see the live version at [www.cabsurf.com](http://www.cabsurf.com/ro/))

The only difference in my CSS is the way I declare the font family:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

But it will look the same even if I leave only Open Sans in the declaration.

I've placed the same text in Google Fonts page above (using inspect element in Chrome) and the text is rendered correctly on their side, so I know the font is ok.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**

Using Chrome 27 / Firefox 22 on MacOS X 10.8.4

Comment: do you properly reset the css in your page?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the the extended glyphs in those weights. When I switch the `<h1>` to `font-weight: 700`, everything looks the same.

Comment: @ArturUdod In the public version no, but in the development version I've also tried the reset, but to no result

Comment: I see same styling here : Firefox22 on PC-windows7

Comment: @kalley If you look closer to the diacritics you'll see that the font is still different and is also slightly thinner, this time. Also, in the Google Fonts, works for every font weight listed :(

Comment: @MilchePatern Sorry, I forgot to mention the OS/Browser. Edited the question.

Comment: Google will use any sub-set of the font it wants. Did you make sure to check the correct boxes when you got the code for it?
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Subsets


When I append `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` to your `<head>`, all the characters look correct

Comment: @kalley That was it! Can you please put it as an answer ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will use any sub-set of the font it wants. Did you make sure to check the correct boxes when you got the code for it?

When I append `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300&subse‌​t=latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`to your `<head>`, all the characters look correct.

Just make sure to check whichever sub-sets you need so you don't get unnecessarily large files.